# Connecting Two Websites with Coding

Tags: python, ojs

I am new to website development, my issue is figuring out what code I need to input so that my two website talk with one another. My two website are built similar to an Amazon platform. Where one site is for clients to input their content and the other site is for the consumer to browse and purchase. I have both built, but need to figure out what coding I need to input so that when a client enters new content or edits content it reflects on the consumer site.

Thank you for any advice or coding possibilities.
Elizabeth

Answer (score 0):

I can't show you any code but you need something like a database. If The websites are basially on the same server and both are accessing to the same folders you could basically also use a normal file but i would recommend making a database. I dont really know much about databases but I am quite sure it should work. Have a look on youtube about how to work with databases. I think you need a bit knoweldge in JavaScript. Depending on the database you are gonna use you also need to know MySQL or rathe the language the database works with. I hope this helped you. If not just reply to this reply